# How to create order in magento 1.9 using soap api

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

My code

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://webisteurl/api/soap/?wsdl');
$sessionId = $proxy->login('user', 'key');

$quoteId = $proxy->call( $sessionId, 'cart.create', array( 'magento_store' ) );
echo "dd";exit;
$arrProducts = array(
    array(
        "sku" => "test",
        "quantity" => 4
    )
);

$resultCartProductAdd = $proxy->call($sessionId,"cart_product.add", array($quoteId,$arrProducts ));
```

it gives error "Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [1001] Can not make operation because store is not exists"

How can I resolve this? Am I doing right?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
in magento admin, create api username and password
System > Web Services > Roles.
Create a new API role
Create a new API user

    <?php

    $api_url_v1 = "http://magento.local/api/soap/?wsdl=1";

    $username = 'mobile';
    $password = 'mobile123';

    $cli = new SoapClient($api_url_v1);

    //retreive session id from login
    $session_id = $cli->login($username, $password);

    //call customer.list method
    $result = $cli->call($session_id, 'customer.list', array(array()));
```

Comment: can you please explain complete process how to create api

Comment: i try your code and i return following message:""SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://local.uri.de/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1' : failed to load external entity \"http://local.uri.de/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1\"\n"" .. i try my url in postman, there it works. did you have add configuration on server or magento side?